# Use Python to get value from an embedded object in json

Tags: python, json

I have a Python request `getAmount` that gets data from an API that returns data in this structure

```
{
    "data": {
      "amount": 5000.0
    },
    "message": "successful",
    "status": 200
  }
```

My code looks like this

```
api_data = json.loads(getAmount.text)
message = api_data["message"]
status = api_data["status"]
```

As seen in my code above, I am able to get value for `message` and `status` key.
I want to get the `amount` value embedded in the `data` key.

Comment: `amtValue = api_data['data']['amount']`

Comment: Bravo! This worked perfectly. Thanks for the help @FishingCode

Answer (score 0):

Here's a potential way to fix it:

When you use `json.loads()`, it generates a string of the json content, instead of this, try using the `json.load()` method, by doing this, you'll get a dict-object which you can directly access. So, the implementation of this on the code will be:
**Note** : If you're using an API, you'll be getting a response in json, so I just created a file-Object

```
fileObj = open('./getAmount.json', 'r')
api_data = json.load(fileObj)
message = api_data["message"]
status = api_data["status"]
```

I hope this answer was helpful. :D

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the viable suggestion but it doesn't solve the challenge completely. The comment below question by @FishingCode is the solution. Thanks.